# Get the latest (date) record for every ID in the MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, date, select, max

I am adding people who are living in a house to a database. Someone moves in in house 1 on the first of August, someone moves in on house 4 on the 5th of August and someone moves in on house 1 again on the 10th of August. What I want to show on a page is the people who are living in a house on for example the 9th of August and the 11th of August.

Example of the database:

```
employee----house-date
1-----------2-----01-01-2012
5-----------7-----01-01-2012
1-----------1-----01-08-2012
3-----------4-----01-01-2012
1-----------8-----01-09-2012
```

First I tried

```
SELECT employee FROM habitants WHERE house='$house' AND date <= '$today' ORDER BY date DESC, employee ASC
```

But this shows one person in multiple houses (e.g. when employee 1 changed houses sometimes)

Then I tried

```
SELECT employee FROM habitants WHERE house='$house' AND date <= '$today' ORDER BY date DESC, employee ASC LIMIT 1
```

But then I get only one person per house

Then I found something on MAX, so I tried

```
SELECT employee, MAX(date), house FROM habitants WHERE house='$house' AND date <= '$today' ORDER BY date DESC, employee ASC GROUP BY house
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY huis' at line 1
```

Can someone show me how to do this in a right way? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use a subquery and `join`:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM habitants h JOIN
     (SELECT house, MAX(date) as maxd
      FROM habitants
      WHERE date <= '$today'
      GROUP BY house
     ) hh
     ON hh.house = h.house and hh.maxd = h.date
WHERE house = '$house';
```

You can also write this as a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM habitants h
WHERE h.house = $house AND
      h.date = (SELECT MAX(date)
                FROM habitants h2
                WHERE h2.house = h.house and h2.date <= CURDATE()
               );
```

Note that you do not need to pass in the current date, under most circumstances.  `CURDATE()` provides the current date (and `NOW()` is the current time).

EDIT:

If you are looking at where *employees* are, then you need to find the maximum date for each employee, not house:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM habitants h
WHERE h.house = $house AND
      h.date = (SELECT MAX(date)
                FROM habitants h2
                WHERE h2.employee = h.employee and h2.date <= CURDATE()
               );
```

Or, alternatively:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM habitants h JOIN
     (SELECT employee, MAX(date) as maxd
      FROM habitants
      WHERE date <= '$today'
      GROUP BY employee
     ) hh
     ON hh.employee = h.employee and hh.maxd = h.date
WHERE h.house = '$house';
```

Comment: Thank you for this, works fine.  
However, what I see now is that employee 8 that switched from house 3 to house 0 (no house) is still showing up today. Exert from the database for employee 8
`employee----house-date
8-----------0-----2015-05-01
8-----------3-----2015-08-07
8-----------0-----2015-08-11`

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!